# OpenAPI 3 specification of Option[]

Tags: scala, swagger, openapi

Let's say I have this case classes as part of some OAS3 specification:

```
case class UserData(userId: String, country: Country)
case class Country(id: String, name: String)
```

Then, the OAS3 specification would be something like this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    UserData:
      type: object
      properties:
        userId:
          type: string
        country:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Country'
    Country:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```

My question is: If a made country as Option, how can I model this?

```
case class UserData(userId: String, country: Option[Country])
case class Country(id: String, name: String)
```

I try putting "nullable: true" but this is not valid:

```
components:
  schemas:
    UserData:
      type: object
      properties:
        userId:
          type: string
        country:
          nullable: true <---- NOT VALID
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Country'
    Country:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```

How can I model this Option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark all of the non optional parameters as required:

```
components:
  schemas:
    UserData:
      required:
        - userId
      type: object
      properties:
        userId:
          type: string
        country:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Country'
    Country:
      required:
        - id
        - name
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
```